# Canonical Way to use JQueryUI Autocomplete with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using Meteor, I'd like to understand the most efficient way to use JQuery UI's Autocomplete with large volumes of server-side data.

I have two working proposals and would like to hear opinions on the differences and if there are any better ways to do the same thing.

Using pub/sub:

```js
// Server
Meteor.publish("autocompleteData", function (theSearchTerm) {
  var query = {
    name: { $regex: theSearchTerm, $options: 'i'}
  };

  return MyData.find(query, options);
});

// Client
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  initAutocomplete($(this.find('.my.autocomplete')));
};

var initAutocomplete = function(element){
  element.customAutocomplete({
    source: function(request, callback){
      var sub = Meteor.subscribe('autocompleteData', request.term, function(){
        var results = MyData.find({}, {limit: 50}).fetch();
        sub.stop();
        callback(results);
      });
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
      // Do stuff with selected value
    }
  });
};
```

Using remote functions (Meteor.Methods):

```js
// Server
Meteor.methods({
  getData: function(theSearchTerm) {
    var query = {
      name: { $regex: theSearchTerm, $options: 'i'}
    };

    return MyData.find(query, {limit: 50}).fetch();
  });
});

// Client
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  initAutocomplete($(this.find('.my.autocomplete')));
};

var initAutocomplete = function(element){
  element.customAutocomplete({
    source: function(request, callback){
      Meteor.call('getData', request.term, function(err, results){
        callback(results);
      });
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
      // Do stuff with selected value
    }
  });
};
```

Which, if either, is the the most efficient way to setup a server-side autocomplete using Meteor with a large dataset?

Comment: I am by far no expert on Meteor (see my many posts here asking for help), but it seems wrong that you are doing pub/sub and have a method to getData.  Not sure why you would need both.

Comment: @CodeChimp Yeah, I know... I've also got it working using pure pub/sub - I'll update the question to make it clearer. I guess what I should really be asking is: is starting and stopping a new sub on each new search event the most performant way to do this?

Comment: Again, no expert, but I think stopping a subscription simply means you are no longer listening to changes from the publisher.  Someone with more Meteor experience please speak up if I am way off base here. If I am correct in my statement, I think the performance hit would be continuous updates over time (for not un-subscribing) VS. a possible larger hit when subscribing when needed. I think the later could be mitigated by narrowing your publication's scope, which it seems you are doing.

Comment: @CodeChimp My feeling is there is only one way to use pub/sub here, as given. If I subscribe outside the scope of the ac search then there's no 'term' and I risk getting ALL the data, bad. I've rewritten the question to Pub/Sub vs. Method Call as a clarification.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I'll offer a few of my thoughts on the subject. As a disclaimer, I'm just a Meteor enthusiast and not an expert, so please correct me if I've said something faulty.

To me, it seems like a potential advantage of pub/sub in cases like these is that data is cached. So when subscribing to the same record set, lookup will be near instantaneous since the client can search the local cache instead of asking the server for data again (publication is smart enough not to push repeated data to the client).

However, the advantage is lost here since you're stopping the subscription, so every time the user types the same search term, data is again pushed to the client (at least, the cursor's added event fires again for every document). In this case I would expect the pub/sub to be on nearly equal footing with Meteor.call.

If you want to cache the data of pub/sub, one way is to take out the sub.stop(). But unless your users have the tendency to search similar terms, caching the data is actually worse since with every letter the user types more data will be stored on the client, perhaps never to be seen again (unless searching is such a prominent feature in your app that the user would benefit from this?).

Overall, I see no compelling advantage with using pub/sub over Meteor methods, though I'm not versed in Meteor well enough to offer more specific advantages/disadvantages between the two. I personally think Meteor methods looks cleaner though.

If you're trying to implement a search feature though, I personally like the [easy-search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) package, which supports this type of server-side search with autocomplete. In any case, I hope you get your question resolved! I'm curious to know the answer too.

Comment: Thanks, useful stuff. Regarding stopping the sub, holding a cache would be very useful indeed, the same searches are used again and again, but do you know if I can repeatedly call Meteor.subscribe() with dynamic terms and still benefit from it? The one thing I don't want to do is subscribe to ALL the data without a term to filter.

Comment: @OliverLloyd Yeah, I also had the same concern. You absolutely don't want to subscribe when there is no search term, since that *will* indiscriminately send over all the documents. It's kind of hard to tell how much of an impact this will make (as it depends largely on the documents' contents themselves) but you could perhaps populate the autocomplete with data only after so many letters have been input, so the amount of data cached is relatively smaller but much more relevant (you said similar searches are made, so searches likely share similar starting letters).