# Subscription on large collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a collection that recently became very large. I used to subscribe to all it's documents has I was performing search on it using a search field in myapp.

With this larger collection it takes a lot of time to load.

What would you recommend to lower the load time but still power search on the whole collection?

Can I subscribe to a part of the collection (performing my search query) through the client?

what I have now:

on my router:

```
waitOn: function(){
  return [Meteor.subscribe('files')];
},
```

on my client (when search button clicked):

```
'click #search':function(e,context) {
  Session.set("keywords",$("#search_input").val());
}
```

the template

```
Template.filwsList.helpers({
  files_results: function () {
    var keywords = new RegExp(Session.get("keywords"), "i");
    var result = Files.find({$or:[{name:keywords},{description:keywords},{tags:keywords}]},{sort: {updatedAt: 1}});
    return result;
  }
})
```

Comment: I asked a question on a similar subject that you might find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225840/canonical-way-to-use-jqueryui-autocomplete-with-meteor. It lists how to search large collections using pub/sub or using a server method, with examples for both.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to define a [publish function](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish) on the server that takes as a parameter the search keyword.

```
Meteor.publish('files', function publishFunction(keywords) {
  check(keywords, String);  // https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check_package
  return Files.find({
    $or: [
      { name: keywords },
      { description: keywords },
      { tags: keywords }
    ]}, {
      sort: ...
      limit: ...
      fields: ...
    }
  ); 
});
```

Then on the client, pass the `keywords` as a parameter:

```
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('files', keywords);
}
```

It's also worth noting that there might be packages doing what you want already, e.g. [autocomplete](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete) or [datatables](https://atmospherejs.com/ephemer/reactive-datatables).

See also Understanding Meteor publish/subscribe.

Comment: For security (and community awareness), I'd recommend always including input checks when answering questions with publish functions.

Comment: The publish function is called every time the client subscribe. In this case, the publication happens on the route, which I guess is the page where the search form is. When the route code is invoked - and so the publication function - the keyword object is still empty (the user have yet to type the keywords)... the search would then use underfined as $or param...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to publish as little data as possible.

Publish (and subscribe to) only the field of the collection that are used in the search (see http://docs.meteor.com/#find ) and write a method that returns the whole `File` object by id and call it after your search (when you are displaying the file content or something).

Other option, you could just do the search server-side, without publishing the `Files` collection, but the result will not be much "meteor-ish"...